# How to find a point that is on the same circle given an angle?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have the following setting:

[image]

I know P1, P2 and the angle alpha, now how do i calculate the coordinates of P3? (Note: P3 is on the same circle with origin P1 and radius P1P2)

The blue lines indicate the coordinate system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula stated above from Wikipedia is usable here to rotate the vector P1->P2 (V12).

```
V12 = [0, -100]
```

When rotated (beware of α is -30 degrees in your drawing) the vector P1->P3 becomes

```
x' = V12(x)*cos(α) - V12(y)*sin(α) = 0*cos(-30) - (-100)*sin(-30) = -50
y' = V12(x)*sin(α) + V12(y)*cos(α) = 0*sin(-30) + (-100)*cos(-30) = -86.6
```

When translated with the point P1 the coordinates for P3 becomes

```
[x, y] = [-50+150, -86.6+210] = [100, 123.4]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you rotate the vector P1->P2 by alpha about P1 you'll get the vector P1->P3. Then knowing P1 you can get P3.

The basic equation for rotation about the origin is:

```
[ cos(α) -sin(α) ] [x]
[ sin(α)  cos(α) ] [y]
```

You might have to change the signs with your coordinate system, but I always have to it by trial and error as I can never remember!

Don't forget - as S.C. Madsen says `sin` and `cos` expect angles to be in radians not degrees.

Wikipeida's article on [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) has more information.

Comment: Thanks. However I cant solve the problem. P1 is (150/210). P2 is (150/110) and alpha is 30. But if i calculated this and draw the point it isn't on the line.

Comment: The problem is that you need to translate P1 to the origin before the rotation and then translate back to its original place.

Answer (score 2):

Complex_To_Vector(Vector_To_Complex(P_2 - P_1) * e<sup>i*alpha</sup>) + P_1.

(Just for fun -- not a serious suggestion)

Comment: Why not serious? It is a good and simple solution, if you ask me.

Comment: Well, thank you, but I'm just worried the level of the answer compared to the level of the question is too high -- I'm concerned it may be more mystifying than helpful/educational to the original author.  But don't let me stop you from upvoting!  :)

Comment: I'm just not sure which solution is faster

Answer (score 1):

Let r be the distance from P1 to P2. Then P3 lies r*sin(α) in the negative x-direction from P1, and r*cos(α) in the negative y-direction from P1. For more details, see [Wikipedia on trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry). Hence P3 has coordinates P1 - (r*sin(α), r*cos(α)).

Sidenote: It's a shame SO doesn't have LaTeX support, like MO.

Comment: Thanks. However I cant solve the problem. P1 is (150/210). P2 is (150/110) and alpha is 30. But if i calculated this and draw the point it isn't on the line.

Answer (score 1):

The angle has to be in radians when invoking sin and cos, you state the angle alpha is 30, so it seems to be in degrees. Other than that I think 'gspr' and 'ChrisF' have given excellent advice on how to solve this.

Comment: Thanks! this solved the problem! Now i have to find out which answer to accept :D all helped!

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. May I suggest you select Fischer's answer as the solution, since he has the lowest reputation of all the people who helped out.